# Size and Version fields in Programs and Features

Tags: .net, wix, installation

I have wix setup.

When I set those properties

```
<Property Id="ARPNOREMOVE" Value="yes" Secure="yes" />
<Property Id="ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT" Value="yes" Secure="yes" />
```

in Programs and Features `Size` and `Version` fields are empty.
Why is that and how to solve it?